# Ruby update not working using two methods

Tags: terminal, osx, upgrade, macintosh, ruby

I tried to install ruby version 1.9.3 with this on my mac 10.6.8:

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby

Oskar-Niburskis-MacBook-Pro:~ oskarniburski$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p362
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.6/i386/ruby-1.9.3-p362.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system.............................................
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkgconfig, libiconv, libyaml, libffi, readline, libksba, openssl, curl-ca-bundle, sqlite3, zlib, gdbm, ncurses...
Error running 'requirements_osx_port_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig libiconv libyaml libffi readline libksba openssl curl-ca-bundle sqlite3 zlib gdbm ncurses',
please read /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/log/1380238189_ruby-1.9.3-p362/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkgconfig_libiconv_libyaml_libffi_readline_libksba_openssl_curl-ca-bundle_sqlite3_zlib_gdbm_ncurses.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

My version:

```
Oskar-Niburskis-MacBook-Pro:~ oskarniburski$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

Output of log file:

```
Oskar-Niburskis-MacBook-Pro:~ oskarniburski$ cat /Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/log/1380238189_ruby-1.9.3-p362/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkgconfig_libiconv_libyaml_libffi_readline_libksba_openssl_curl-ca-bundle_sqlite3_zlib_gdbm_ncurses.log
[2013-09-26 19:30:17] requirements_osx_port_libs_install
requirements_osx_port_libs_install () 
{ 
    __rvm_try_sudo port install "$@" || { 
        typeset ret=$?;
        rvm_warn "There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.";
        return $ret
    }
}
current path: /Users/oskarniburski
command(16): requirements_osx_port_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkgconfig libiconv libyaml libffi readline libksba openssl curl-ca-bundle sqlite3 zlib gdbm ncurses
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
--->  Computing dependencies for autoconfError: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
```

And then tried to install using MacPorts, but it also did not work again. Any ideas?

```
Oskar-Niburskis-MacBook-Pro:~ oskarniburski$ sudo port install ruby19
Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed; most ports will likely fail to build.
--->  Computing dependencies for ruby19Error: Unable to execute port: can't read "build.cmd": Failed to locate 'make' in path: '/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin' or at its MacPorts configuration time location, did you move it?
```

Here is my path right now:

> /opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/Users/oskarniburski/.rvm/bin

Neither of the 'which -a make' nor locate -b '\make'. The first has which command not found, and the for the latter locate:illegal option --b

Comment: Umm, did you read the message? `Warning: Xcode does not appear to be installed;` Doesn't that suggest a possible [course of action](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.xcode) :) ?

Comment: Rakso, try installing the latest Xcode following the instructions [here](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.xcode.snowleopard).

Comment: Hey terdon I have xcode 3.2.6, and that is the necessary file for installing xcode on Mac according to that link. So how should I proceed. Is there for some reason, like my path variable, as to why xcode is not being taken into account. I must seem like a hapless soul!

Comment: Open a new terminal and post the output of `echo $PATH`. Also, remember to ping me (@terdon) otherwise I don't get notified of your comments.

Comment: @terdon the path is above in the question now!

Comment: Could you join me in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux) so we can figure this out? Just click on that link and it will open the U&L.stackexchange chat room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem 1 : `make`

The first problem is that ruby needs to be compiled and that is usually done through [`make`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/make.1.html) which will read settings from a `Makefile` and then call the compiler. On OSX `make` is installed with `Xcode` which installs its tools in `/Developer/usr/bin` rather than the `/usr/bin` where one would expect. This directory is not in the default `$PATH` so any executables in it are not found by the shell.

You can fix this for your user by adding this line to your `~/.bash_profile` (make sure to add it before `export $PATH` line) :

```
PATH="/Developer/usr/bin:$PATH"
```

However, this will still not be accessible to any commands running as root (with `sudo` for example). I recommend you add this directory to the default path. Open `/etc/profile`, find the line that defines the path there and add the diretory to it. I am on a Linux system but it should look something like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
```

Just add the directory to the end of that so it looks like this:

```
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/Developer/usr/bin"
```

If you don't want to change the default, you can link `make` to a directory that is in the default `$PATH`:

```
 sudo ln -s /Developer/usr/bin/make /usr/bin
```

You'll have to do this for everything that's in `/Developer/usr/bin` so I really recommend you change the default.

#### Problem 2 : finding the new version

At this point you should be able to install ruby with

```
$ sudo port install ruby19
```

That exits correctly but your ruby version does not seem to be updated:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [universal-darwin10.0]
```

This is because, [by default](http://guide.macports.org/#reference.variables), `port` installs its files in `/opt/local` and will install your ruby executable as `/opt/local/bin/ruby1.9`. Yet another directory that is not in your `$PATH`. So, you can either repeat the process above and add `/opt/local/bin` to your `$PATH` or you can link the `ruby1.9` executable to a directory that is in your path. If you add `/opt/local/bin` to your `$PATH`, you will be able to run v1.8 with `ruby` and v1.9 with `ruby1.9`. If you want all your existing scripts to switch to v1.9, I recommend you make `/usr/bin/ruby` point to the new version.

The old version at `/usr/bin` is actually a symlink:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/ruby 
rwxr-xr-x 1 root wheel 76 25 Jun 2010 /usr/bin/ruby -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby
```

This means you can safely delete it and replace it with a link to the new version:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby; sudo ln -s  /opt/local/bin/ruby1.9  /usr/bin/ruby
```

If you ever want to revert and make `ruby` run v1.8,  just run the inverse command:

```
$ sudo rm /usr/bin/ruby; sudo ln -s  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/Current/usr/bin/ruby  /usr/bin/ruby
```

If all has gone well, your default `ruby` is now v1.9:

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27 revision 41675) [x86_64-darwin10]
```

Comment: Wonderful answer!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this gist. Shows how to install it for Mountain Lion.

- [Ruby, RVM and Mountain Lion](https://gist.github.com/zenkay/3237860)

Highlights how to using either MacPorts or Homebrew. Once you get that squared away it shows how to install using `rvm`.

Comment: Hey I only have Snow leopard on my mac! I have tried going through homebrew to get requirments, but homebrew itself is saying I have a lot of problems, which I have tried to fix with brew doctor to no avail/

Comment: You need to install xcode!

Comment: I do have xcode installed though. I can access it through finder and it is on ym computer.

Comment: What version or xcode? I know that can be a sticking point.

Comment: Hey the version is 3.2.6.